# What is the 'perl-dynamic' executable

Tags: perl, hp-ux

Investigating an issue with multiple Perl installations on our (HP UX IA64 system), I came across an executable called `perl-dynamic`. What is this and what exactly does it do?

More importantly, how do I know which perl executable it actually points to (we have multiple versions mixing version numbers and architectures installed).

```sh
bash-4.4$ ll /usr/bin/perl    
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root       sys             18 Jan  8 16:34 /usr/bin/perl -> /opt/perl/bin/perl
bash-4.4$ ll /opt/perl/bin/perl
lrwxrwxrwx   1 bin        bin             14 Jan  8 16:45 /opt/perl/bin/perl -> ./perl-dynamic
```

Is this a magical perl binary which decides which version and architecture to use?

Answer (score 6):

```
$ perl -V
```

Will show you the details.

Both perl-static and perl-dynamic are built with the same configuration (at least for what I can see on my HP-UX 11.31) and both are built with `-Dusedl`

`perl-static` is linked with `libperl.a` (or linked with all `.o` files), whereas `perl-dynamic` is linked using `libperl.so`. You can check the differences with `ldd perl-static` and `ldd perl-dynamic`.

There is no functional difference

Comment: Thank you. So they don't point to the binaries in `/opt/perl32/bin/` at all?